# JRViewer is not refreshing

Tags: java, swing, jasper-reports

I want to display *JasperReports*'s report on jpanel using JRViewer.

[image]

In my application(as shown in above image), i have one jcombobox and a jbutton . i have multiple names of report in the jcombobox and on click of the jbutton i want to show the report in jrviewer. when i click the button for the first time it works button when i click the button after selecting other report name from combobox it is not working.

below is the code i am using

```
reportPanel = new JPanel();
reportPanel.setBackground(Color.white);

JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(reportPanel);
scrollPane.setBounds(20, 150,dim.width-60, 370);

mainPanel.add(scrollPane);   

String pathUrl = System.getProperty("user.dir");

String district_cd = getKeyForValue(districtMap, districtCombo.getSelectedItem().toString());
String jasper_name = getKeyForValue(reportMap, reportCombo.getSelectedItem().toString());

String filename = FilenameUtils.removeExtension(jasper_name);

Map reportParameter = new HashMap();  
reportParameter.put("district_cd", district_cd);

JasperReport report = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(pathUrl+"//"+jasper_name);

JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report,reportParameter,patchConnection);

JRViewer jrviewer = new JRViewer(jasperPrint);

reportPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
reportPanel.add(jrviewer);

reportPanel.revalidate();
reportPanel.repaint(50L);

mainPanel.revalidate();
mainPanel.repaint(50L);

stopWaitCursor(frame);
frame.repaint();
```

Comment: Please provide a minimum working code.

Comment: The code i have provide is written on the button click event .. i cannot provide you the whole code because of confidentiality..

Comment: the possible reason for this issue might be due to refreshing proble of the jpanel.

Comment: Sorry, Can not debug with out a minimum working code.

Answer (score 0):

It works, but you can't see it ...
Everytime your methode is adding a new scrollpane with a new reportpanel with a new JRViewer and so on. But you did not clear the old ones. Remove the older components from the mainpanel before.

Comment: The revalidate() + repaint() is not needed; probably from your try/error tests :-)

Answer (score 0):

reportPanel.removeall();

done the works.
Now it's working properly.
Thanks All for providing the support